# Edit the css of a material ui popover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material ui popover and I am trying to add style in css to it.

This is my popover

```
    import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import gastronomia from 'assets/experiences/gastronomia.jpg';
import productos from 'assets/experiences/productos.jpg';
import giftcard from 'assets/experiences/giftcard.jpg';
import diversion from 'assets/experiences/diversion.jpg';
import deporte from 'assets/experiences/deporte.jpg';
import belleza from 'assets/experiences/belleza.jpg';
import gastronomiaExperiences from 'data/gastronomia';
import productosExperiences from 'data/productos';
import giftcardExperiences from 'data/giftcard';
import diversionExperiences from 'data/diversion';
import deporteExperiences from 'data/deporte';
import bellezaExperiences from 'data/belleza';


// Proptypes definitions to the component.
const propTypes = {
  /** Custom root className. */
  className: PropTypes.string,

};

// Default props definitions.
const defaultProps = {
  className: null,
};

// Component's styles
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'block',
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: '50%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      maxWidth: '70%',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
    },
    '& .experiences-column': {
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      textAlign: 'center',
      '&.col1': {
        width: '36.31%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '&.col2': {
        width: '63.69%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '& .experience': {
        padding: 2,
        position: 'relative',
        '& img': {
          width: '100%',
          display: 'block',
        },
        '& .experience-title': {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
'& .deporte': {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        '& img': {
          width: '30px',
          display: 'block',
        },
   },        
      },

paper: {
    border: '1px solid',
    padding: theme.spacing(1)

  },
    },
  },
}), { name: 'ExperiencesStyle' });


/**
 * Component used to render a grid of experiences.
 *
 * @param {object} props - The component's props.
 * @returns {object} React element.
 */
const Experiences = memo(


    const useCustomStylesByIds = ({ ids }) => {
  const myStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
    let stylesObj = {};

    ids.forEach(id => {
      stylesObj[getPaperKey(id)] = {
        backgroundColor: idToColorMapper[id]
      };
    });

    return stylesObj;
  });

  return myStyles();
};

const getPaperKey = id => `paper-${id}`;

const idToColorMapper = {
  gastronomia: "red",
  giftcard: "blue",
  deporte: "yellow",
  productos: "cyan",
  diversion: "green",
  belleza: "orange"
};

const ids = [
  "gastronomia",
  "giftcard",
  "deporte",
  "productos",
  "diversion",
  "belleza"
];

function SimplePoppers() {
  return ids.map(id => <CustomPopper key={id} id={id} />);
}

const CustomPopper = props => {
  const classes = useCustomStylesByIds({ ids });
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const { id } = props;
  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    const experience = (img, title, id, popoverCategory) => (
      <div
        className="experience"
        aria-describedby={id}
        id={id}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={img}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
            { title }
          </Typography>
        </div>

         <Popper
          id={id}
          open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id || false}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          className={id}
         >
          <div  className={classes[getPaperKey(id)]}>
            {
              popoverCategory.map(url => (
              <Grid 
              md={4}
              >
                <img
                  key={id}
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  className="lazyload"
                  src={url}
                  alt={ title }
                />
              </Grid>
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>

    );

    console.log();
    return (

      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA', 'gastronomia', gastronomiaExperiences)}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD', 'giftcard', giftcardExperiences)}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE', 'deporte', deporteExperiences)}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS', 'productos', productosExperiences)}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN', 'diversion', diversionExperiences)}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA', 'belleza', bellezaExperiences)}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  },
);

// Component proptypes.
Experiences.propTypes = propTypes;

// Component default props.
Experiences.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Experiences;
```

I have tried adding style to paper class but have no results 
I want to make the background a different color for each popover and make the width of the popover be the same with of the parent div. And move the popover up over the experience it corresponds to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer updated based on author comment**

---

You can give each `Popper` a special class name, and dynamically create this classes using `makeStyles`.
Let's say your id's are 'gestronomy','giftcard','deporte' (assuming you have your id's in advance. If you don't, you need to modify my answer to suit your needs) 
And let's say you want to name your classes *paper-gestronomy*, *paper-giftcard*, *paper-deporte*:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";

const useCustomStylesByIds = ({ ids }) => {
  const myStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
    let stylesObj = {};

    ids.forEach(id => {
      stylesObj[getPaperKey(id)] = {
        backgroundColor: idToColorMapper[id]
      };
    });

    return stylesObj;
  });

  return myStyles();
};

const getPaperKey = id => `paper-${id}`;

const idToColorMapper = {
  gastronomia: "red",
  giftcard: "blue",
  deporte: "yellow",
  productos: "cyan",
  diversion: "green",
  belleza: "orange"
};

const ids = [
  "gastronomia",
  "giftcard",
  "deporte",
  "productos",
  "diversion",
  "belleza"
];

export default function SimplePoppers() {
  return ids.map(id => <CustomPopper key={id} id={id} />);
}

const CustomPopper = props => {
  const classes = useCustomStylesByIds({ ids });
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const { id } = props;
  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        {id}
      </button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        <div className={classes[getPaperKey(id)]}>{id} with custom color</div>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the example above, I wrapped `makeStyles` with my own function, which takes ids as arguments, makes an object for each id. 
example returned object is:

```
{
  'paper-gestronomy': {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  'paper-giftcard': {
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  'paper-deporte': {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: Thanks but nothing happened... And how could I give the Popper a className using the id as the class name to give each popper a different css style?

Comment: I edited my answer according to your comment, let me know if that helped @NaNodine

Comment: How would I declare the id in advance? I have the id inside the experience const how can I declare 6 id with different values?

Comment: I get this error Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level. refering to this line export default function SimplePoppers() {

Comment: @NaNodine Regarding the first comment: do you know the id's values? or you get them from server? 
Regarding the second comment, did you try the code sandbox link? it's working there without any error. [Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-e7gd9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I updated my question with the complete component.. I assign the id in the experience const..

Comment: You need to put the ids in "idToColorMapper" object (the object job is to map id to a color which you define in advance). check the updated [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-m52wq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) , it's with your id's names, it should give you a general idea how to implement this in your code.

Comment: @NaNodine unfortunately i can't fully reproduce your issue because I don't have all your code. I commented out what I don't have and made it work. Is this what you meant? [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-eny40?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)